# How to perform deep update with the SAP Cloud SDK

Tags: odata, sap-cloud-sdk

We are currently trying for performance reasons to execute a deep update on an entity structure exposed as OData service using the SAP Cloud SDK. From our understanding using the replacingEntity() strategy on the update request, we want to send the complete structure down to the OData service similar to what is described for the deep insert use case here:

https://blogs.sap.com/2017/12/07/step-20-with-s4hana-cloud-sdk-create-and-deep-insert-with-the-virtual-data-model-for-odata/

However, when doing so we noticed that only the entity fields are sent and none of the navigational properties. Having debugged/browsed through the SDK this seems to be the intended behaviour as can be seen in the following method:

```
com.sap.cloud.sdk.s4hana.datamodel.odata.helper.FluentHelperUpdate.getQueryBuilder() {
    [...]
    final Map<String, Object> fieldsForUpdate = getFieldsForUpdate(); // does not include navigations
    [...]
}
```

Is there some configuration option when making the request for making a deep update? Or is one supposed to retreat to batch requests to the backend instead? In case this is not a supported a remark whether this is on the roadmap would also be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Tim, you figured out correctly that this "deep update" is not supported by the SAP Cloud SDK at the moment. What kind of OData service do you want to integrate with: Which OData version? Which system does expose it (CAP, S/4HANA, etc.)? Have you tried to perform this "deep update" with Postman? So, are you sure that the target system/service does support this "deep update"?

Comment: Hi Emdee, yes, we can assert that his will work, because it is a custom implemented OData service. However the OData service is implemented on the SCp. We could however also have such custom services on S/4HANA side for use cases currently not yet supported by the published API, so the question is whether this is something which will be supported in the future, or if this requires an explicit use case for a concrete system usage.

Answer (score 2):

At the time of this writing, the SAP Cloud SDK for Java does not provide the functionality "deep update". I will update this answer if this feature will be covered.